# Jquery selector - logging a specific text field within a html javascript code

Tags: jquery-selectors, html-parsing, cheerio

I am using Node js, myhttp and Cheerio to extract some data from a webpage.

I am having difficulty in extracting a specific text 'var key = xxxxxx' that appears in the html under
script -> function

Have tried

```
var _key = $("script:contains('var key')"); 
console.log('var key ' + _key);
```

the full  content is logged.

When I try

```
var _key = $("script:nth-child(5)", this).text().trim(); 
console.log('var key ' + _key);
```

nothing is logged.

Is there any way of getting the key alone (the value **d1f0573f-2413-46f4-946d-bdd6d9** in the example code below) stored as a variable in my code under **var _key**?

Similarly, any way to obtain the full **url** present in the next line "**document.hiddenform.action**"

Any help appreciated. Have been looking at various forums and not found anything that works.

Thanks

Sample Html file

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
        <script language='javascript' src='../JS/Abc.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language='javascript' src='../JS/de.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript">
            <!--
            function abc(){
                var v_temp = "../abcDispPage.jsp";
                AjaxFun.sendRequest("GET",v_temp,funDisply);
            
            }

            function Validate()
            {    
                if(document.login.requLog.value=="")
                {
                    alert("Please enter valid User id");
                    document.login.requLog.focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    var key  =  'd1f0573f-2413-46f4-946d-bdd6d9';
                    document.hiddenform.action = "../ShowImage.jsp?43a091d4-6290-4f9f-8c8e-3ac1630adca2="
                    document.hiddenform.submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:check2fa();func_get_reig();">
        <form name="hiddenform" method='post'>
            <input type="hidden" name="requLog" value=""/>

        </form>

        //html code for page
                
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need regex for this:

```
let key = $.html().match(/var key  =  '(.*)'/)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Highly appreciated. That works to get the 'var key'.  How do i modify this to get the url from "hiddenform.action"?

Comment: I have been able to work this out. Thanks once again for your help